# Equirectangular approximation in PHP

Tags: php, distance, geo, haversine

I'm trying to calculate the distance between two latitude/longitude coordinates using the equirectangular approximation formula in PHP, but I get different results than the haversine formula (which I know is correct) for certain longitude coordinates.

```
define('EARTH_RADIUS', 6371);

function equirectangularRad($latFrom, $lngFrom, $latTo, $lngTo) {
    $latDelta = $latTo - $latFrom;
    $lngDelta = $lngTo - $lngFrom;

    $x = $lngDelta * cos(($latFrom + $latTo) * .5);
    $radius = sqrt(($x * $x) + ($latDelta * $latDelta));

    return $radius * EARTH_RADIUS;
}
```

Distances always seem to be calculated crossing the prime meridian instead of the shortest distance. i.e. from coordinate (lat=0, long=-180) to (lat=0, long=180) along the equator, the distance should be zero. Instead the function returns the circumference of the earth along the equator; roughly 40030 kilometer.

The problem seems to stem from the calculation of `$lngDelta`, but all implementations I can find, for any programming language, uses this same formula. Am I missing some important detail or is this formula truely not a drop-in replacement for haversine (ignoring the obvious accuracy difference)?

For reference; this is the haversine implementation I use:

```
function haversineRad($latFrom, $lngFrom, $latTo, $lngTo) {
    $latDelta = $latTo - $latFrom;
    $lngDelta = $lngTo - $lngFrom;              

    $latSin = sin($latDelta * .5);
    $lngSin = sin($lngDelta * .5);
    $radius = 2. * asin(sqrt(($latSin * $latSin) + cos($latFrom) * cos($latTo) * ($lngSin * $lngSin)));

    return $radius * EARTH_RADIUS;
}
```

Comment: `$lngDelta = ($lngTo - $lngFrom) % 360;`?

Comment: @mudasobwa, modulo 360 (or rather 2 * pi) wouldn't work. Inversion is needed somewhere. I have some limited success using `$lngDelta = abs($lngTo - $lngFrom); $lngDelta = min($lngDelta, (2 * pi()) - $lngDelta);`, but this still produces rather large errors at the poles (which I can life with) and pretty much slows it down to roughly the speed as haversine (which makes using equirectangular approximation pointless).

Answer (score 5):

I don't know where you got your formulas. The 3 formulas below all calculate distance between 2 coordinates.

Equirectangular

```
function Equirectangular($lat1,$lng1,$lat2,$lng2){
$x = deg2rad($lng2-$lng1) * cos(deg2rad($lat1+$lat2)/2);
$y = deg2rad($lat1-$lat2);
$R = 6372.8; // gives d in km
$distance = sqrt($x*$x + $y*$y) * $R;
return $distance;
}
```

**EDIT**
Modified Equirectangular() to consider comment. Have made the lng values absolute using php abs() function. It starts to drift from Haversine when lng2 passes from negative to positive.

```
function Equirectangular($lat1,$lng1,$lat2,$lng2){
$lng1 = abs($lng1);
$lng2 = abs($lng2);
$alpha = $lng2-$lng1;
$x = deg2rad($alpha) * cos(deg2rad($lat1+$lat2)/2);
$y = deg2rad($lat1-$lat2);
$R = 6372.8; // gives d in km
$distance = sqrt($x*$x + $y*$y) * $R;
return $distance;
}
```

Haversine

```
function Haversine($lat1,$lng1,$lat2,$lng2) {
  $deltaLat = $lat2 - $lat1 ;
  $deltaLng = $lng2 - $lng1 ;
  $earthRadius = 6372.8; // 3959 in miles.
  $alpha = $deltaLat/2;
  $beta = $deltaLng/2;
  $a = sin(deg2rad($alpha)) * sin(deg2rad($alpha)) + cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * sin(deg2rad($beta)) * sin(deg2rad($beta)) ;
  $c = 2 * atan2(sqrt($a), sqrt(1-$a));
  $distance = $earthRadius * $c;
  return $distance;
}
```

SphericalLawOfCosines

```
function SphericalLawOfCosines($lat1,$lng1,$lat2,$lng2) {
 $lat1 = deg2rad($lat1);
 $lat2 = deg2rad($lat2);
 $deltaLng = deg2rad($lng2-$lng1);
 $R = 6372.8; // gives d in km
$d = acos( sin($lat1)*sin($lat2) + cos($lat1)*cos($lat2) * cos($deltaLng) ) * $R;
return $d;
}
```

Equirectangular is the simplest but less accurate. For the other 2 The one to use depends on the distances involved.See this [**Answer**](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4906/why-is-law-of-cosines-more-preferable-than-haversine-when-calculating-distance-b). 
For small distances (on the order of 1 meter or less) use Haversine. For larger distances use Spherical Law of Cosines.

Results from formulas

0,-179 to 0,-179 Equirectangular 0 km Haversine 0 km

0,-179 to 0,-159 Equirectangular 2224.526851 km Haversine 2224.526851 km

0,-179 to 0,-139 Equirectangular 4449.053703 km Haversine 4449.053703 km

0,-179 to 0,-119 Equirectangular 6673.580554 km Haversine 6673.580554 km

0,-179 to 0,-99 Equirectangular 8898.107406 km Haversine 8898.107406 km

0,-179 to 0,-79 Equirectangular 11122.634257 km Haversine 11122.634257 km

0,-179 to 0,-59 Equirectangular 13347.161109 km Haversine 13347.161109 km

0,-179 to 0,-39 Equirectangular 15571.68796 km Haversine 15571.68796 km

0,-179 to 0,-19 Equirectangular 17796.214811 km Haversine 17796.214811 km

0,-179 to 0,1 Equirectangular 19798.288978 km Haversine 20020.741663 km

0,-179 to 0,21 Equirectangular 17573.762126 km Haversine 17796.214811 km

0,-179 to 0,41 Equirectangular 15349.235275 km Haversine 15571.68796 km

0,-179 to 0,61 Equirectangular 13124.708423 km Haversine 13347.161109 km

0,-179 to 0,81 Equirectangular 10900.181572 km Haversine 11122.634257 km

0,-179 to 0,101 Equirectangular 8675.654721 km Haversine 8898.107406 km

0,-179 to 0,121 Equirectangular 6451.127869 km Haversine 6673.580554 km

0,-179 to 0,141 Equirectangular 4226.601018 km Haversine 4449.053703 km

0,-179 to 0,161 Equirectangular 2002.074166 km Haversine 2224.526851 km

Comment: These have the same problem I describe in my question: `Equirectangular(0,-179,0,179)` returns 39819.030640452, `Haversine(0,-179,0,179)` returns 222.45268514219. Clearly Equirectangular is not calculating the shortest distance. `SphericalLawOfCosines` returns 222.45268514218, nearly the same as Haversine. The Equirectangular formula has trouble with distances crossing the -180/180 degree longitude meridian.

Comment: @Martijn have modified `Equirectangular()`to consider comment.

Answer (score 0):

You reuse `latDelta` one of the uses have them added, the other subtracted.

http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

have working javascript.

translated ..

```
$x = ($lngTo-$lngFrom) * cos(($latTo+$latFrom)/2);
$y = ($latTo-$latFrom)
$d = sqrt($x*$x + $y*$y) * EARTH_RADIUS;
```

Comment: I'm not seeing the difference between my function and the formula on that page. (in fact, that page was used as reference).